# How to add a dynamic class shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I add a shortcode in wordpress where you can dynamically assign any class name which a user would enter from the admin. for example

```
[border-dashed]
```

where [border-] would always be defined but the user can put the second bit which would be the class name defined in the css, depending on what border they want to show on the front end.

```
[border-dashed]
[border-double]
[border-single]
```

I'm sure you get the point.

Thanks.

Comment: I would use shortcode arguments for that. For example `[border-dashed] = [border type="dashed"]`. In this case you only need to register one shortcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would actually be with `attributes`.  Here is how you could accomplish that:

```
add_shortcode('border', 'border_shortcode');

function border_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    if( isset( $atts['style'] ) )
    {
       return "<hr class='border {$atts['style']}'/>";
    }  
}
```

Then you can use your shortcode like this:

```
[border style="dashed"]
[border style="double"]
[border style="single"]
```

Obviously, you would also need to add the styles to your CSS:

```
.border {
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:black;
}
.dashed {
  border-style:dashed;
}
.double {
  border-style:double;
}
.single {
  border-style:single;
}
```

Comment: thanks I will try this code out and let you know how i get on.
Instead of <div> I am going to be using the <hr> tag instead. Would this still work? 

Also, If I am not going to have any content, do I still need the $content variable?

Comment: Yes, using an `<hr/>` tag should work as well.  And you are correct - `$content` should be unnecessary.  I have updated my answer to reflect the  necessary changes.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,

This just output the shortcode as it is even when i insetered it through the HTML editor

Comment: Jonathan, this worked perfect. The css path was wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I add a dynamic title in the same way so that that when the title is changed from the shortcode it shows that title on the front end

Comment: To make sure I understand what you want, the final HTML should be like this: `<hr class="border dashed" title="Seventy" />`, and the shortcode would look like this: `[border style="dashed" title="Seventy"]`, or are you wanting to add a `<h2>` title, for example ?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, that is correct you're spot on. I want to be able to add a h2 title whcih I can then style after in the css. thanks